# Java: Returning Int Values/Multiple Values

Tags: java

The code needs to check if String letter is in String message, and how many times it's in String message. The return statement says that it cannot convert int count into a boolean, so I'm not sure how to return that value. How can I return count to the main method so that the code prints the number of times String letter can be found in String message?

```
public class StringFind
{
  /** findLetter looks for a letter in a String
   * @param String letter to look for
   * @param String text to look in
   * @return boolean true if letter is in text
   * After running the code, change this method to return
   * an int count of how many times letter is in the text.
   */
   public boolean findLetter(String letter, String text)
   {
       boolean flag = false;
       int count = 0;
       for(int i=0; i < text.length(); i++)
       {
           if (text.substring(i, i+1).equalsIgnoreCase(letter))
               {
              flag = true;
               count++;
           }
   }
  return flag;
   }
public static void main(String args[])
{
    StringFind test = new StringFind();
    String message = "Apples and Oranges";
    String letter = "p";
    System.out.println("Does " + message +  " contain a " + letter + "?");
    System.out.println( test.findLetter(letter, message));
    System.out.println(message + " contains " + letter + " " + count + " times.");
}
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you need to return true if the value appears if you're already saying how many times the value appears. They mean the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

Change the return type from `boolean` to `int` and change `return flag` to `return count`. If you return the count the flag is redundant. The count contains the same information: the letter was found if `count > 0`.

Answer (score 2):

your answer can be found in the code:

```
* @return boolean true if letter is in text
* After running the code, change this method to return
* an int count of how many times letter is in the text.
```

Just change the header of the function to:

```
public int findLetter(String letter, String text)
```

That way you want to say "hey I will return a number".

Then change the last line in the function:

```
return count;
```

You are done. The println will print your return count-value.

**Happy coding!**

Answer (score 0):

You should modify the signature of method `findLetter` to return `count` and for boolean compare the returned count to be greater than 0:

```java
public int findLetter(String letter, String text) {
    int count = 0;
    char cc = Character.toLowerCase(letter.charAt(0));
    for (char textLetter : text.toLowerCase().toCharArray()) {
        if (textLetter == cc) {
            count++;
        }   
    }
    return count;
}
```

Test would look like this:

```java
StringFind test = new StringFind();
String message = "Apples and Oranges";
String letter = "p";
int count = test.findLetter(letter, message);
System.out.println("Does " + message +  " contain a " + letter + "?");
System.out.println(count > 0);
System.out.println(message + " contains " + letter + " " + count + " times.");
```

---